# Java applet no longer functional in Internet Explorer under Java 8u60

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, applet

I maintain a few applets used for a website and Java 8u60 makes them just not fire. I'm not sure exactly what's going on.

Here is how I declare the tag for IE:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
   <param name="code" value="com.mysite.myapplet" />
   <!-- other params -->
</object>
```

One detail: the applet must not fire on page load, but on a button click, so the above tag is generated by Javascript, which injects the HTML into a div's `innerHTML` property. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the workaround I found: use an `APPLET` tag.

"But all the doc says to use `OBJECT` for IE support?"

I know. But even Java's own deployJava.js outputs an `APPLET` tag.

Apparently this is a bug specifically introduced in 8u60 which makes injected HTML `OBJECT` tags inoperative.

So instead, inject this:

```
<applet code="com.mysite.myapplet">
    <param name="classid" value="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" />
    <!-- other params -->
</applet>
```

That should work. Applets that fire automatically on opening the page can be left as objects.

Comment: Time to get rid of that applet.  It's not 1995 anymore.  Make an HTML5/CSS3 UI.  You'll be better positioned for the long run.

Comment: @duffymo Would that I could. This is governmental stuff, tied to legal obligations of client-side execution of very specific tasks.

Comment: God help us.  Our government mandates stupidity.  Make a plan; tell the customers; execute the plan.  I don't know what's worse: applets or IE.

Comment: @duffymo they must be in the pockets of Big Applet!

Comment: I wish you success in persuading them to do better.

Comment: @duffymo It's a legal battle, not a software one. I'm just a single, lonely consultant facing a behemoth of administration and lawyers. If I can pick my battles, this is one I'd rather not fight. But I appreciate the sentiment you expressed.